# SQLGetData doesn't work in the same way after install KB5019959

Tags: c++, sql-server, data-access

I'm trying to retrive a **float value** from a SQL Server database **into a double variable**, I'm using this code:

```
bool CDataAccess::GetValue(UINT col, double& value)
{
    int retCode = SQLGetData(m_hstmt, col, SQL_C_DOUBLE, &value, 0, &m_cbValue);
    ...
}
```

That code was working fine until last week when Windows update KB5019959 was installed; if I uninstall this update everything works fine again.

If I use SQL_C_FLOAT as parameter or change column type to double, it works, but that change will carry a hugh refactor...

Comment: Would something like this work?
`float tmp; int retCode = SQLGetData(m_hstmt, col, SQL_C_FLOAT, &tmp, 0, &m_cbValue); *value = tmp;`? My C++ is rusty...

Comment: Hi Joachim! Yes, if I use a float variable it works, but I need that my method `GetValue(UINT col, double& value)` will be able to work when database column was float or double.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a possible change in behavior with how `BufferLength` is treated with doubles in the later versions of the driver when 0 is passed as the value.  0 used to work however no longer does for the default driver.

The following will return the correct data from my testing:

```
    SQLDOUBLE value;
    SQLLEN lengthIndicator = 0;
    SQLRETURN r;
    r = SQLGetData(hstmt, col, SQL_C_DOUBLE, &value, sizeof(value), &lengthIndicator);
```

NOTE: `sizeof(value)` being passed as BufferLength vs `0` like before

We have encountered the same bug in QGIS which implementing the above fix has resolved the issue (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50865)

Comment: With sizeof(value) everything works again, many thanks!!